# Nested routes not rendering in router-view

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nested-routes

I'm setting up what is going to be a large system, so I want to have decentralised router.js files for every module. Each of them would have routes arrays declarations that would be pushed to the main routes array.

So for now I have a kind of root of routes file, which have the `VueRouter` instances and settings, and it imports the first level of route.js files to build the routes array.

### main routes.js file

```js
import DashboardRoutes from './views/dashboard/routes'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {// Root public site
      path: '/',
      component: () => import('./views/pages/Index'),
      children: PagesRoutes
    },
      name: 'page_error',
      path: '*',
      component: () => import('./views/error/Error')
    }
  ].concat(
    DashboardRoutes
  )
})
```

### module (first level) routes.js file

```js
import InventoryRoutes from './inventarios/routes'

const routes = {
  path: '/panel',
  component: () => import('./Index'), // This Index has a layout with a router-view in it
  children: [
    // Inicio del panel
    {
      name: 'dashboard',
      path: '',
      component: () => import('./Dashboard'),
    }
  ].concat(
    InventariosRoutes
  )
}

export default routes
```

### Components (second level) routes.js file

```js
const routes = {
  path: 'inventario',
  name: 'panel_inventario',
  component: { template: '<router-view/>' },
  children: [
    // Productos y servicios
    {
      name: 'panel_inventarios_productos-servicios',
      path: 'productos-servicios',
      component: () => import('./productos-servicios/ProductosServiciosHome'),
    },

  ]
}
export default routes
```

In the components tree of `vue-tools` I see an `AnnonymousComponent` in the place where my children's router-view should be.

## Update

I just create an external component to name it and check if it's being rendered like this

### Components (second level) routes.js file

```
const loader = {
  template: `
    <div class="InventarioLoader">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  `,
  name: 'InventarioLoader'
}

const routes = {
  path: 'inventario',
  name: 'panel_inventario',
  component: loader,
  children: [
    // children go here
  ]
}
```

Now I see my `InventarioLoader` component, but I still don't see my children components rendered in it

## Update

I see this error on the console

> You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

Comment: Perhaps because `{ template: '<router-view/>' }` **is** an anonymous component? Try adding a `name` to it

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question or problem is. Are you actually seeing any issues or were you just confused about the naming of a component?

Comment: @Phil I tried with `<router-view></router-view>` and didn't work either, this is a solution that I've seen in similar questions here, but didn't worked for me.

The problem is that the component is not being rendered, but I do know that the router is working cuz I have a watcher to the route object to show a title in the nav and it is working

Comment: Are you navigating to the correct route, ie `/panel/inventario/productos-servicios`? Also, I'd move the `*` route to the very end of the routes definition. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#catch-all-404-not-found-route. In fact, that's probably your problem

Comment: Like I said, the router is redirecting me to the right route, I see that on a display title I have in another component that watches for route changes. The thing is that the component it's not being rendered

Answer (score 2):

> You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

By default, Vue does not compile string templates. This is for performance reasons.

> Since the runtime-only builds are roughly 30% lighter-weight than their full-build counterparts, you should use it whenever you can

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only

Either create a real single-file component or use a render function

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

const RouterView = Vue.component('router-view')

const loader = {
  name: 'InventarioLoader',
  render (createElement) {
    return createElement(RouterView)
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much bro, I figured it out myself but I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Apparently now you can't point a route to a inline component like `{template:'<router-view/>}` and my solution was to create a loader component with that template and use it on the parent route